# A doubt regarding continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Since $\Bbb Q$ is countable, there exists a bijection $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb Q$. Now consider the same function $f$ with the codomain changed to $\Bbb R$. That is, $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb R$. My question is, whether the given function is continuous or not(the metric involved is the usual metric).

I'm not able to wrap my head around this thing. I request anyone to shed some light on this matter.

Comment: Don't you mean $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: With usual metric, $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete, so any map $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous

Comment: Isn't every subset of $\mathbb N$ open?

Comment: You mean $f:\;\mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (you only mentioned a change of codomain)?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo.

Comment: *Which* is the metric that you're using then, if it's not the usual one.

Comment: the usual metric ofcourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, although it is somewhat counterintuitive at the first glance. A moment's further thought can dispel the delusion. Recall the definition of continuity of a real-valued function $f$ defined on a metric space at a point $c$. Take the metric space to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ for illustration. The continuity requirement is that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-c| < \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(c)| < \varepsilon$. Now if $f$ maps $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and if $c \in \mathbb{N}$, then every $0 < \delta < 1$ is such that $|x-c| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(c)| = |f(c) - f(c)| = 0 < \varepsilon$. So by definition $f$ is continuous at $c$. Since $c$ was arbitrary, we proved that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{N}$. Since $f$ was arbitrary, we proved that every $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

We may note that this continuity is in some sense "boring".

Answer (score 1):

I think the heart of the issue is you have not really specified what topology you want $\mathbb{N}$ to have. Lets not think about topologies induced by metrics.

If you pick the discrete topology, every function is continuous. If you pick the other trivial topology, then since the interval $(0,1)$ contains some but not all rational numbers, no bijection $f$ extended in this way will be continuous.

So what topology does $\mathbb{N}$ inherit from "the usual" metric? It will be endowed with the discrete topology, and so any function at all will be continuous, in particular the one you want to consider.